# how to maintain conversion from number to character in R after writing to file

Tags: r

```
str(stratified_1)

'data.frame':   60197 obs. of  30 variables:
 $ srch_id                    : int  6 52 61 81 106 118 119 139 151 160 ...
 $ date_time                  : int  8500 15379 42277 48907 31091 32805 16006 23669 15969 23629 ...
 $ site_id                    : int  14 16 5 5 5 5 23 24 26 22 ...
 $ visitor_location_country_id: int  100 31 219 219 219 219 181 219 39 92 ...
 $ visitor_hist_starrating    : int  272 272 272 272 272 272 272 272 272 272 ...
 $ visitor_hist_adr_usd       : int  2444 2444 2444 2444 2444 2444 2444 2444 2444 2444 ...
 $ prop_country_id            : int  100 215 219 219 219 219 55 219 202 99 ...
```

I want to convert 'prop_country_id' to 'character' data type.
Therefore, I've implemented this conversion code.

```
stratified_1$prop_country_id = as.character(stratified_1$prop_country_id)
str(stratified_1)

'data.frame':   60197 obs. of  30 variables:
 $ srch_id                    : int  6 52 61 81 106 118 119 139 151 160 ...
 $ date_time                  : int  8500 15379 42277 48907 31091 32805 16006 23669 15969 23629 ...
 $ site_id                    : int  14 16 5 5 5 5 23 24 26 22 ...
 $ visitor_location_country_id: int  100 31 219 219 219 219 181 219 39 92 ...
 $ visitor_hist_starrating    : int  272 272 272 272 272 272 272 272 272 272 ...
 $ visitor_hist_adr_usd       : int  2444 2444 2444 2444 2444 2444 2444 2444 2444 2444 ...
 $ prop_country_id            : chr  "100" "215" "219" "219" ...
```

and saved the file.

```
write.csv(stratified_1, "train.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

However, once I read the file back, 'prop_country_id' was 'integer' back again.

```
stratified_1 = read.csv("train.csv", header = TRUE)
str(stratified_1)

'data.frame':   60197 obs. of  30 variables:
 $ srch_id                    : int  6 52 61 81 106 118 119 139 151 160 ...
 $ date_time                  : int  8500 15379 42277 48907 31091 32805 16006 23669 15969 23629 ...
 $ site_id                    : int  14 16 5 5 5 5 23 24 26 22 ...
 $ visitor_location_country_id: int  100 31 219 219 219 219 181 219 39 92 ...
 $ visitor_hist_starrating    : int  272 272 272 272 272 272 272 272 272 272 ...
 $ visitor_hist_adr_usd       : int  2444 2444 2444 2444 2444 2444 2444 2444 2444 2444 ...
 $ prop_country_id            : int  100 215 219 219 219 219 55 219 202 99 ...
```

How can I save the file with 'prop_country_id' as character?

Comment: ensure that you have this option while creating and reading the csv stringsAsFactors=FALSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be helpful... you can specify the class of a column when you read in the csv:

```
stratified_1 = read.csv("train.csv", header = TRUE, colClasses=c("prop_country_id"="character"))
```

Comment: hmm, it works for me :/ should mean you don't have to do the part where you convert to character at all, you would just specify character each time you read the file in.  Sorry, I'll keep thinking but i'm not sure why that isn't working for you.

Comment: Oh, it works! Thanks. I mistook it for write.cvs. Umm, I actually wanted to use the file in a different program (weka), so it solves problem within R but the file itself is still in numeric data type... Anyway, thank you so much!